# Cannot connect remotely to Z: drive

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hard-drive, mapped-drive

I am trying to figure out why I can't connect to `Z: Drive` from home to school.

I was able to connect to `Z: drive` on my laptop when I was connected to the schools secure connection, but now I am at home and cannot connect.

I have the VPN up and running just fine, but when I try to map network drive `Z:` it keeps giving me an error when I try to log in.

The error is ***The specified network password is not correct***.

I have tried several times to type in my password to no avail.

I feel like it might be a firewall issue, but perhaps it is something else?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot map it implies you cannot open it in Windows Explorer as well ? How are you trying to login, `DOMAIN\USER ID` & `Password` ?

Comment: "\\DOMAIN\X\USER ID" X is first letter of USER ID, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to preceed your username with your school's internal domain.

For example:

`STUDENTS\joe.blogs`

Where "STUDENTS" is the internal domain name and "joe.blogs" is your username.

Note the backslash - "\" - this is very important.

Enter your password as normal - do not change anything about this.

Comment: yes I typed "\\school's internal domain\X\User ID" X is my first letter of user ID. There is also another error saying "The local device name is already in use".

Comment: You're not understanding how it works. The "\\server\path\to\your\folder" is separate from the username/password box that my answer refers to because your question doesn't ask about the address. I think you need instructions and guidance from your school IT department rather than us helping.